# Quality issue with audio conversion

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I am converting a mono PCM Wave file with 16bit and 48 kHz to a mono signed linear PCM AU file with 16bit and 8 kHz suitable for telephony using javax.sound.sampled:

```
public void convertSO(final String in, final String out) throws Exception {     
    try (final AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(in))) {
        final AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 8000f, 16, 1, 2, 8000, false);
        try (final AudioInputStream cais =  AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(af, ais)) {
            AudioSystem.write(cais, AudioFileFormat.Type.AU, new File(out));
        }
    }
}
```

It works like that and it sounds okay, but if I compare the quality with a similar conversion done with SoX like

```
sox in.wav -b 16 -r 8000 -c 1 -e signed-integer out.au
```

the high frequency range of the conversion done with javax.sound.sampled sounds scratchy while with SoX it sounds pretty smooth.

Both output files have the same size and there is no difference comparing their properties with `mediainfo`.

I am mainly wondering where the difference can come from. Is it the conversion of sample rate from 48 kHz to 8 kHz that SoX does a better job at? Or does SoX apply some fancy filter or psychoacoustic model to improve the sound quality?

Comment: The better program might be filtering out high frequency noise before doing the decimation.  If that is not done, it will wrap around the new sampling frequency (which is itself in the audible range!).  You might try looking at spectral energy in something like audacity.  You could also record a ramp from 1-24 KHz and see what each program does with that - ideally you should get a ramp up to 3.5 KHz and then fade to nothing.  If instead you get a bouncung series of reflected ramps up and down, the conversion was done without alias filtering.

Comment: The source code that does the downsampling in SoX is here: http://sourceforge.net/p/sox/code/ci/master/tree/src/downsample.c It's not very well documented, but it looks like they use some sort of carry-over between samples in `p->carry`. This could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I won't accept my own answer as solution because it is not a solution, but for anyone interested, I have tried to apply [phrogz low pass filter](http://phrogz.net/js/framerate-independent-low-pass-filter.html) before doing the conversion:

```
public void convertSO(final String in, final String out) throws Exception {     
    try (final AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(in))) {
        final int frameSize = ais.getFormat().getFrameSize();
        if (frameSize != 2) {
            throw new Exception("Works only with frame size == 2");
        }

        final int smoothing = 10;
        final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final byte[] buf = new byte[frameSize];
        ais.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
        int value = (buf[1] << 8) | (buf[0] & 0xff);
        while (ais.read(buf, 0, buf.length) != -1) {
            final int currentValue = (buf[1] << 8) | (buf[0] & 0xff);
            value += (currentValue - value) / smoothing;
            final byte[] smoothed = {(byte)(value & 0xff), (byte)(value >> 8)};
            baos.write(smoothed);
        }
        final AudioInputStream smoothedAis = new AudioInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                baos.toByteArray()), ais.getFormat(), baos.size() / frameSize);

        final AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 8000f, 16, 1, frameSize, 8000, false);
        try (final AudioInputStream cais =  AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(af, smoothedAis)) {
            AudioSystem.write(cais, AudioFileFormat.Type.AU, new File(out));
        }
    }
}
```

It was not so easy for me because `AudioInputStream` lets you only read at least `frameSize` bytes and maybe what I did to smooth over two bytes per iteration is clumsy, but it works and the high frequency range is gone.

The result is indeed without "scratchiness" but also muffled compared to the conversion done by SoX and I guess it is the carry-over mentioned by Ghostkeeper that does the trick in SoX.

Which I won't try to implement in Java now because I simply don't get it :-/